# How to sort the list value of a defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
d['A']=[('a',20,30), ('b', 13, 1)]
d['B']=[('c',2,1), ('b', 3, 21)]
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = sorted(v, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[2]), reverse=True)

print(d)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [('a', 20, 30), ('b', 13, 1)], 'B': [('b', 3, 21), ('c', 2, 1)]})
```

I want it to be sorted based on the 2nd and 3rd value of the list in reverse order. But the result is wrong. For example, For 'A' it should be:

```
'A' = ('a', 30, 20)
```

EDIT:

Sorry. My original solution is what I want and I am confused.

Comment: It should be integer. I corrected.  @Julien

Comment: you are never reassigning the contents the tuples contained in your lists, so why would they change?

Comment: what about d[k] = sorted()? Doesn't that get new sorted values?

Comment: It's still unclear what operation you want to do... [ask] and [mre]

Comment: sorted(...) sorts the list of tuples according to your lambda, doesn't modify the tuples inside them.

Comment: i.e. the lambda is used to compare the tuples, but doesn't actually modify them.

Comment: Again the question is why should `('a', 20, 30)` become `('a', 30, 20)` but `('b', 3, 21)` doesn't become `('b', 21, 3)`? you haven't clearly explained what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `defaultdict`'s default type only takes effect when the key doesn't yet exist, which is useful for things like appending to a collection without `KeyError` for fresh keys!

If you have mixed types and are trying to sort 'em, just create a custom class which does what you want

You could also add a comparator (only `__lt__` is needed) instead if you want to make the instances themselves also sortable!

```py
class NamedSortableContainer:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        assert len(args) >= 2
        assert isinstance(args[0], str)
        self.name   = args[0]
        self.values = sorted(args[1:], reverse=True)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.name == other.name:
            return self.values < other.values
        return self.name < other.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"NSC[{self.name}, {','.join(str(x) for x in self.values)}]"
```

usage example

```py
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['A']=[NamedSortableContainer('a',20,30), NamedSortableContainer('b', 13, 1)]
>>> d['b'].append(NamedSortableContainer('c',2,1))     # avoids KeyError
>>> d['b'].append(NamedSortableContainer('b', 3, 21))
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [NSC[a, 30,20], NSC[b, 13,1]], 'b': [NSC[c, 2,1], NSC[b, 21,3]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by my comment, try this:

```
def my_reverse(tup):
    return (tup[0],) + tup[:0:-1]
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = sorted(map(my_reverse, v), key=lambda tup: tup[1:], reverse=True)
```

or this?

```
def my_sort(tup):
    return (tup[0],) + tuple(sorted(tup[1:], reverse=True))
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = sorted(map(my_sort, v), key=lambda tup: tup[1:], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you means exactly.. but

This can be helpful (not Pythonic though)

```py
for key in d:
    d[key] = [tuple(list(item[:1]) + sorted(item[1:], reverse=True)) for item in d[key]]
```

The result `d` after operations follows:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [('a', 30, 20), ('b', 13, 1)], 'B': [('c', 2, 1), ('b', 21, 3)]})
```

Is it same with what you want to get...?!

Keep hacking!

Comment: That's what I want, but why doesn't my solution work? which looks simpler.

Comment: @marlon

The reason why your solution doesn't work is that you are comparing wrong items.

In your code snippet `tup[1]` and `tup[2]` is not `20`, `30` but tuple itself. For example change `'a'` to `'z'` and run your code and see the result then you can figure it out what I mean.

Hope that can be helpful